# summary of duplicate records in the table with R

Tags: r, math, ggplot2, plyr

I have dataset in *.csv like

```
a ,b
1 ,2
3 ,4
5 ,2
```

In fact, this is a very large (more than 500,000 records) dataset with unix time in a and names in b. I need to build a scatter plot, and I decided to count the repeating names more than 10 times for a certain period of time and build a graph on them. But when I try

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

compl <- ddply(num.csv,.(b),nrow)
```

)
then I only have two columns in the table, and I lose time column. How do I make a new column in a table and build plots whith the condition of repeatability of names?

Thats what i expect

```
a ,b ,repeatsOfB
1 ,2 ,2
3 ,4 ,1
5 ,2 ,2
```

and plot ony on rows wuth repeatsOfB > 10

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package `dplyr` to count number of records per group(s) and filter out the ones that appear less than 10 times:

```
compl <- num.csv %>% # take num.csv data.frame
  group_by(a, b) %>%  # group_by a and b (similar to SQL group by)
  summarise(n = n()) %>% # count occurences of a and b
  filter(n > 10) # keep only those where number of rows is greater than 10
```

Note: if you don't want to exclude rows with `n <= 10` simply remove the last row.

Comment: Error in summarise_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) : 
  argument ".data" is missing, with no default

Comment: You need to have a data.frame object called num.csv in order to use the code. I took the name from the example in your question .

Answer (score 0):

I set up a minimal working example first - if I understood your question correctly, we don't actually need the time column.
I am not entirely sure about what you actually want to plot: Is it counts of individual names in b, when there are more than ten? I propose a solution within the tidyverse (as suggested in http://r4ds.had.co.nz).

I first group by the column, count the individual instances, filter all occurrences > 10 and pipe this into a ggplot function:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# set up a minimal example:
x <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
data <- tibble(b=sample(x, size = 1000, replace = T))

data %>% 
  group_by(b) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  filter(n>10) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=b, y =n)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: thx, this is usefull information, but i need time data as XVAR, i'll try parts of your solution anyway